# Using jQuery to submit a form with post vars

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to use `.ajax` to submit a form without refreshing the page. But at present, it just refreshes the page and doesn't even reach my script.

I'm calling the function as so. The string being passed through is the URL for the script I wish to run (and submit the post vars to)

```
<form onsubmit="submitForm('login-register/submit-registration.php')" method="POST">
```

And the function `submitForm()` looks like this:

```
function submitForm(url){
    var url = 'actions/'+url;
    console.log(url);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
            $('#success-message').fadeIn("fast");
        }
        });
}
```

I am seeing my console.logs correctly, so it must be reaching the script, but it is not posting the vars to the script (or even running the script at all, it appears).

Comment: Your page will refresh either way. So, as a start, put a "return false;" just before the last }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `onsubmit` handler to return `false` in order to prevent default browser page reload:

```
<form onsubmit="return submitForm('login-register/submit-registration.php')" method="POST">
```

And in JS:

```
function submitForm(url){
    var url = 'actions/'+url;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
            $('#success-message').fadeIn("fast");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

As the further improvement, you could get rid of inline event handlers in favor of unobtrusive event binding model. For example like this:

```
<form action="login-register/submit-registration.php" method="POST">
```

and then you no longer need `submitForm` function, you just bind `onsubmit` event:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'actions/' + this.action,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function () {
            $('#success-message').fadeIn("fast");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. Is it possible for me to pass another piece of data to the function? E.g I would like to pass a success message to the function (as the type of message required would depend on where the form was submitted from, this would need to be set in the HTML)

Comment: Yes, you could do it like this `onsubmit="return submitForm('login-register/submit-registration.php', 'Success message')"` and then `function submitForm(url, message) { ...`.

Comment: For the second approach I would set data atrtibute: `<form action="login-register/submit-registration.php" method="POST" data-message="Success message">` and retrieve it like: `$(this).data('message')` later.

Answer (score -1):

html

```
<form id="myForm" >
```

js

```
   var myForm= $('#myForm');
     myForm.submit(function (ev) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'login-register/submit-registration.php',
                data: myForm.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                   //something
                }
            });

            ev.preventDefault();
        });
```

I think this is cleaner solution since you would have cleaner html

Comment: This does not work as per the functionality of the original code because the URL needs to be passed to the function, not hardcoded in. This solution would not be useable for different forms.

Comment: oh, sorry, I missed that, in that case @dfsq response seems most obvious solution